# Can I make install-tl write an installation profile without actually installing?

Tags: texlive, installing

The question is in the title, really. I want to prepare several installation profiles for use on Travis (skipping compiled documentation, fonts, etc.), but I can't figure a way to do this without having `install-tl` complete its run each time.

How can I do a dry run of `install-tl`?

Comment: I would like to know too. But we can search for examples of profiles, here's one: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/support/texlive.profile

Comment: And here: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu/blob/master/example.profile (more complete example)

Comment: You can see this build log (https://travis-ci.org/abntex/limarka/builds/190389924) and choose which you want and add "1" to it, example to add "avantgar" add a line with  "avantgar 1". Here's my travis file: https://github.com/abntex/limarka/blob/testes-com-latex/.travis.yml